# Remove or hide summary row in grouped row of telerik winform gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid

I have `Telerik WinForm` grid view that has several rows. I used summary row that calculate sum of column for me. I used grouping in `Telerik WinForm` grid view. I just want have one summary row at bottom of grid view not in all grouped rows.

Comment: Try to add some thing similar like Grid summary instead of Group summary.

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu: how can i add grid summary? could you please give me sample?